# FolderBrowserDialog does not show network location in windows 8

Tags: vb.net, networking, windows-8, vb6, folderbrowserdialog

On Windows 8 when we use FolderBrowserDialog, the network drives are not displayed. It works fine if we run the same program on Windows 7 or windows xp. But in openfiledialog both these network location folder are visible. I want added network places which appear in my computer to be appear in FolderBrowserDialog window also.Is it bug with windows 8 or can i do it anyway?

**UPDATE**
In windows 8 browse folder dialog will show mapped network place,but added network location will not appear. There are so many link about it,But none of them helped me.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767400/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8

Comment: maybe this is about the same issue mentioned on:[social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8) they mention creating a new DWORD entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System with the name EnableLinkedConnections and value 1

Comment: @RaphaelSmit I saw that link before posting this.I tried it but didnt work. My application is 32 bit. So should i change some other registry?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between 32bit and 64bit when it comes to this registry key(in those cases 64bit resides under a "Wow6432Node" which isn't the case here) i can't reproduce this bug as i'm on win7, looks like its a diffrent issue though with the same consequences.

Comment: problem is only in windows 8. Also while creating new registry should i select dword(32-bit)value or dword(64-bit)value?

Comment: Can you show code you're using?  It could help.  There may be a new flag required, for example.